# representing time (not date) in momentjs

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

We have been happily been using momentjs for representing dates and timestamps.

However, I have just been looking into a problem we have with representing times (not of a specific date). For instance, we would like to represent a "market close" time.

A duration is almost what we need (Interpreting as Hours/min/sec after midnight.) However, ideally, it would be a time in a specific timezone, but NOT associated with any given day. In the past we have used a `Date` on day 0 of unix time for this, but I am a bit unsatisfied with this. For one thing, its nice to have `date + time == timestamp` work. Any suggestions for best practices?

Answer (score 1):

You can just represent durations as milliseconds and use moment add function to calculate durations from a specific date and time, for example:

```
var date = new Date();
var duration = 1000;
var newDate = moment(date).add(duration, 'ms');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And then store the timezone separately? I was hoping there was some "standard" abstraction to handle this for me, as I would think this is a common problem.